Create wallet using private key
How to create a wallet address using the existing private key and the wallet goes into the keystore folder using web3js?

I’m not getting the exact question though. Do you want to get the wallet address corresponding to a signer (whose private key is being used to create the signer object)?

like ethers.Wallet("0xfffffffffffffffffffffyourprivatekeyhexffffffffff"); ? or ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJson() ?
